# Testing QR code reader

Tags: iphone, xcode

I created an App that reads QR Codes, but I can't test it in the simulator because you can't use the camera in the simulator.

I know I should try it on a device, but should I buy the license to do so?
Is there another way to test it? Otherwise I can't go ahead with the project.

Comment: You could try importing an image file and pretending that it's camera input to see if your reader is working.

Comment: If you know some iphone developer that already has a licence, he could run the app on your device and check if everything works ok. After that the application will work for few months and expire.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe to the apple developer program, in order to test on device. There are no other ways (AFAIK) to test against the device's camera.

However, you could import an image, into your app's bundle, and get your code to process that image rather than the camera input. This isn't a good way to test though, as it doesn't test your code against the real-world situation of a constantly changing camera input.

Comment: then necessarily pay 99 $ just to try an app?

Comment: you're going to have to pay it in the end!

Comment: Yes it is necessary. But anyway **you have to test any app you create on a device** (and that's not restricted to iPhone development!) because even  if the simulator is a great tool, you can't test all the cases with it. Especially the simulator doesn't have limited memory as a real device do (**this could obviously make your app crash on device** if you don't manage memory correctly, especially if you manipulate large amount of data like images) and much more stuff. So beyond the testing of the camera itself, **testing on a real device is necessary**, whatever your app (and targeted device).

Comment: my app is just a temporary thing on a university project, I do not need to publish it or anything, so I do not need to pay, that is the problem.

Comment: Even w/o the camera thing, you can't say an app is working correctly if you don't test it on a real device. If you are new to iPhone development, I bet you do have memory leaks and memory mgmt problems (as this is one tricky thing to manage for new comers to ObjC) that are important to solve if you want your app to be considered as stable, and you app working on the simulator if far from ensuring these probable mem issues won't make your final app crash. (Hope your teachers won't test your final work on a real device!)

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing my answer after seeing your comment that this is a university project that doesn't need to go into the app store.

The reality is that in the end, if this project needs to be deployed onto a device for any reason (whether for you to test, or for some lecturer to review your project etc), the application **will** need to be signed with the credentials from an actual paid account.

Guess the only question is how and who will create that account. E.g. if its a funded project or something, you could try including this cost in the plan.

Hope it all works out!